# Constructing Manifolds: Submersion

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, derivatives

Given a smooth manifold $M$ and a topological space $N$.

Consider a local homeomorphism $F:M\to N$ with $\mathrm{im} F=N$.

Then one can turn the target space into a smooth manifold via:
$$\psi:=\phi\circ F^{-1}$$
*(After suitable restriction!)*

Moreover, the surjection becomes a submersion:
$$\mathrm{rk}\mathrm{D}F\equiv\dim N$$

How to prove this?

Comment: Damn $x^3$... Is there still something one can deduce from it?

Comment: Well, what's $\phi$?

Comment: @JoBe By convention this is a coordinate map for $M$ of a corresponding chart.

Comment: @TroyWoo META: There's not really a universial convention for this. I once read somewhere that ``differential geometry is the invariance under notation'' or something like that, so maps like this should be specified I think

Comment: @JoBe: Nice quote ^^ yet it is meant to be a coordinate map of a chart.

Comment: @JoBe That's a common joke about DG. :P The reality is that differential geometry is about properties invariant under coordinate changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the statement is meant to be interpreted as follows:

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $X$ be a topological space. Suppose we are given a local homeomorphism $F:M\to N$ with $\operatorname{im} F=N$. Then $N$ is a topological manifold, and it has a smooth structure with the property that $F$ is a submersion.

Unfortunately, this is false.

There are two problems, one easily fixed, the other not so easily.

The first problem is that $X$ need not be Hausdorff, so if you include the Hausdorff property as part of your definition of a manifold, then $X$ need not be one. A counterexample is given by letting $M = \mathbb R\times \{0,1\}$ (two disjoint copies of $\mathbb R$), letting $X$ be the quotient space obtained by identifying $(x,0)$ with $(x,1)$ for all nonzero $x$ (called "the line with two origins"), and letting $F$ be the quotient map. This problem is easily fixed by adding the stipulation that $X$ is Hausdorff (or, if you prefer, by allowing non-Hausdorff manifolds).

The second, more serious problem is that there many be no way to endow $X$ with such a smooth structure. Here's a counterexample (inspired by your comment about $x^3$): Let $M=\mathbb R$ with its usual smooth manifold structure, $X=\mathbb S^1$ with its usual topology, and $$F(x) = (\cos 2\pi x^3,\sin 2\pi x^3).$$  Suppose there were some smooth structure on $\mathbb S^1$ such that $F$ is a submersion. Because dimension is a topological invariant, it follows that $\dim X = \dim M = 1$, and therefore $F$ is a local diffeomorphism. Note that $F(0) = F(1) = (1,0)$.  Thus there are neighborhoods $V_0,V_1$ of $(1,0)$ in $X$, $U_0$ of $0$ in $\mathbb R$, and $U_1$ of $1$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $F|_{U_0}\colon U_0\to V_0$ and $F|_{U_1}\colon U_1\to V_1$ are diffeomorphisms.  By shrinking all four neighborhoods, we can also assume that $V_0=V_1$. Then $(F|_{U_0})^{-1}\circ (F|_{U_1})$ is a diffeomorphism from $U_1$ to $U_0$. But a direct computation shows that this map is 
$$x\mapsto \sqrt[3]{(1/2\pi)\arcsin (\sin 2\pi x^3)},$$ which is not smooth at $x=1$ because the argument of the cube root vanishes there.

Here's a theorem that is true:

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $X$ be a topological space. Suppose we are given a covering map $F:M\to X$, such that the covering automorphism group acts smoothly and properly on $M$. Then $X$ is a topological manifold, and it has a unique smooth structure with the property that $F$ is a submersion.

This follows from Theorem 21.13 of my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (2nd ed.).

Comment: Just what I thought.